# Java error when using phantm to scan PHP project

Tags: java, php, scala

I am trying to scan my PHP project with [Phantm](http://lara.epfl.ch/web2010/phantm).
I downloaded the release.jar and am running :

```
    java -jar /path/to/my/phantm-1.0.6.jar
```

I get the following exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at phantm.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 13 more
```

I have read online it could be because scala wasn't installed.
I downloaded and unzipped scala and added its path to .bash_profile

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

I must be missing something else... I am running OS X Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
scala /path/to/my/phantm-1.0.6.jar
```

Works for me with Scala 2.9.2. The Phantm documentation must not have been updated with the move (?) to Scala, because the Scala classes definitely aren't in that jar.

Alternatively you could specify the path to the Scala runtime explicitly (you may need to change the paths to the jars, of course):

```
java -cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scala-library.jar:phantm-1.0.6.jar phantm.Main
```

If you already have Scala installed, though, I don't see any reason to prefer this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did get me a step further, it now fails with : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java_cup/runtime/Scanner
 at phantm.phases.ParsingPhase$$anonfun$1.apply(ParsingPhase.scala:12)...

Comment: @samo: In that case it looks like there are some serious problems with the jar release. I'd suggest building from [the source](https://github.com/colder/phantm), and possibly filing an issue there or contacting the maintainers in some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the second problem was caused by missing JFlex. I wrote up the solution [here](http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2012/php-type-mismatch-detection-with-phantm/)